# Firestore Rules - Check if auth.uid is inside child of collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've been trying to solve this issue for some time now, also reading some places that what I am trying to do is in fact not possible at this point because it is not currently possible to iterate through any data with Firestore rules. However, here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have two separate collections in root "/users" and "/groups". Each group has document with an id (group ID), which then again consists of a collection called "members", each containing an id which contains a document referring to the specific user id. Much like this:

```
/groups/groupIdOne_Random/members/someRandomMemberId/{id: someUserIdHere}
```

What I want to do, is to create a rule that allows me to check if the "id" related to the sub-collection of members holds the exact id as the response.auth.uid. This is the "closest" I've come to a possible solution:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /groups/{groupId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
    }
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}


service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /groups/{groupId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupId)).data.members;
    }
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there in any way, shape or form that I can at least do some kind of validation using this approach that I currently have? This might not be the best architecture, but it is what I have now - so all help would be greatly appreciated. Is it possible to use some kind of function placed in a parent location to do some type of checking?

All help is greatly appreciated, and I do also hope that a solution to this can also help a lot of people, as I can't be the only one with this kind of database architecture. Solution will be upvoted and marked as answered to help others in the future as well.